# Modify a byte of a C# color int or uint

Tags: c#, pointers, colors, bitmap, int

I'm working with bitmaps in C#, and as you know bitmaps are usually stored as 24bpp or 32bpp in memory (when locked). After extracting the int color value of a pixel, I need to read one byte at a time to get R, G, B and edit the same bytes to modify RGB respectively. Is there a way using pointers to modify any given byte of a 4-byte 32-bit int? Or maybe I can create a `struct` and cast the int to a struct that allows access/modification of individual bytes?

```
int color = 0xFFAABB

// attempt to read individual bytes of an int
int R = *((*color));
int G = *((*color)+1);
int B = *((*color)+2);

// attempt to modify individual bytes of an int
*((*color)) = R;
*((*color)+1) = G;
*((*color)+2) = B;
```

I need such a method for fast reading/writing of individual bytes. If there is an `unsafe` method to work with such pointers I don't mind that too. I cannot convert each pixel to a `Color` object since its too slow for high-speed image manipulation.

Comment: did  not get it correctly.. are you trying to modify the color at each pixel of the bitmap?

Comment: Why not use Color.FromArgb()? You can then used color.R/G/B.

Comment: @Carra - Your method is pathetically slow. Just try converting every numeric color value to an OOP Color object per pixel and see what speeds you get with image manipulation. I need to work with the bytes very fast, and so I'm trying to avoid the bitshifting method. OOP is out of the question.

Comment: @Geotarget. You're right, it's slow. When I had to do this I used a class named FastBitmap which uses unsafe methods and is a lot faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally what I do is create a struct as you've said:

```
public struct Pixel {
    public byte Blue;
    public byte Green;
    public byte Red;
    public byte Alpha;
}
```

Then I have a utility functions such as:

```
public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Pixel colour) {
    Pixel* pixel = GetPixelAt(x, y);
    *pixel = colour;
}

public Pixel* GetPixelAt(int x, int y) {
    return (Pixel*)((byte*)_bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer() + y * _width + x * sizeof(Pixel));
}
```

Then you can just call it like this:

```
Pixel p;
p.Red = 255;
p.Green = 0;
p.Blue = 0;
p.Alpha = 255;

SetPixel(0, 0, p);
```

`_bitmapData` is the `BitmapData` structure returned via `LockBits`.

EDIT:

From comments. This is how you would convert them:

```
// from pixel to int
Pixel p;
p.Red = 0;
p.Green = 0;
p.Blue = 0;
p.Alpha = 0;

int* i = (int*)&p;

// from int to pixel
Pixel p2;

p2 = *(Pixel*)&i;
```

Untested, but should be okay.

Comment: Without the unsafe code? You're switching your requirements.. you've stated above you want unsafe code.. (in @Hamlet's answer).

Comment: No, your code is good, I meant without the image pointer code like the Scan0 and stuff. That is confusing me and I just need to see code to convert an int to a Pixel struct and back.

Comment: Editted. Hopefully that's what you meant.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very very much. So there's no cost to cast int to Pixel and back? I hope it does not allocate memory for a new Pixel object like a normal OOP object?

Comment: Your `Pixel` object will be allocated.. there is no way to avoid that. It is a `struct` though, so it will be allocated on the stack..

Comment: Worth (?) to point out that byte order counts when using pointers... Here I see a BGRA struct layout. OP stated an RGB layout. And most pixel datas today are ARGB layouts. Maybe worth pointing out things like endianness and `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=4)] [FieldOffset(0)] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] public byte A;`

Answer (score 2):

To use pointers you must use unsafe code. But you can achieve what you want using shift and bitwise operators.

```
// attempt to read individual bytes of an int
int r = (color & 0x00FF0000)>>16;
int g = (color & 0x0000FF00)>>8;
int b = (color & 0x000000FF);

Console.WriteLine("R-{0:X}, G-{1:X}, B-{2:X}", r, g, b);
// attempt to modify individual bytes of an int
int r1 = 0x1A;
int g1 = 0x2B;
int b1 = 0x3C;
color = (color & ~0x00FF0000) | r1 << 16;
color = (color & ~0x0000FF00) | g1 << 8;
color = (color & ~0x000000FF) | b1;

Console.WriteLine("Color-{0:X}", color);
```

You can wrap this snippet in structure as you wish.

This is solution with unsafe code, you must set allow unsafe code in your build options.

```
using System;

namespace PixelTest
{
    public unsafe struct Pixel
    {
        private int _color;

        public Pixel(int color)
        {
            _color = color;
        }

        public int GetColor()
        {
            return _color;
        }

        public int GetR()
        {
            fixed(int* c = &_color)
            {
                return *((byte*)c + 2);
            }
        }

        public int GetG()
        {
            fixed(int* c = &_color)
            {
                return *((byte*)c + 1);
            }
        }

        public int GetB()
        {
            fixed(int* c = &_color)
            {
                return *(byte*)c;
            }
        }

        public void SetR(byte red)
        {
            fixed (int* c = &_color)
            {
                *((byte*)c + 2) = red;
            }
        }

        public void SetG(byte green)
        {
            fixed (int* c = &_color)
            {
                *((byte*)c + 1) = green;
            }
        }

        public void SetB(byte blue)
        {
            fixed (int* c = &_color)
            {
                *(byte*)c = blue;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Pixel c = new Pixel(0xFFAABB);
            Console.WriteLine("R-{0:X}, G-{1:X}, B-{2:X}", c.GetR(), c.GetG(), c.GetB());
            c.SetR(0x1A);
            c.SetG(0x2B);
            c.SetB(0x3D);
            Console.WriteLine("Color - {0:X}", c.GetColor());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why unsafe? If you are worries about performance, i say you that bitwise operators is very fast. Why you want to use unsafe code?

Comment: "I say you" that bitwise operators aren't as fast as direct byte access. Just count the number of ops for read/write and see for yourself.

Comment: Try solution and test for performance against with bitwise operation and tell me know about results.